# git beanstalkapp staging branch has all changes from master branch but master doesn't have all changes from staging

Tags: git, version-control, branch

We use beanstalkapp to manage our code reviews, deployments etc.
We have a staging Branch and a master Branch.

Our process is to locally

> git checkout master && git pull (Always checkout master and get latest)
>   git checkout -b NAMEOFBRANCH (Create a new branch off of MASTER to work on)
>   Make our changes
>   git add . && git commit -m 'My commit message' (Add everything changed and commit)
>   git push -u origin NAMEOFBRANCH (Push the commit up to beanstalkapp)

In beanstalkapp, I see my branch. I change the base branch to staging and merge my branch into staging. Beanstalkapp is automatically configured to deploy to our staging server.

Test my changes on our staging site.

All looks good, I go back to my branches in beanstalkapp, make sure the base branch is master and I merge my branch with master (after a code review).

I can then deploy to our production server. All is good as far as what is on staging server and what is on production server.

When I compare staging with master, beanstalkapp shows that staging has all the changes from branch master.

When I reverse that comparison, I see a bunch of Revisions that are not on staging but not on master.

How can this be if I merge the same branch first on staging branch and then on master? How do I make them in sync? There is a strict policy to never sync staging to master (for obvious reasons) but master to staging is ok (which I have tried).

Answer (score 0):

**The comparison in beanstalk is actually compare the commits which exist in one branch and not exist in another.** Let illustrate by below graphs:

Assume the branch structure looks like below at beginning:

```
…---A master
…---B  staging
```

After `git checkout -b newbranch`, and commit changes `C` and `D` on it:

```
…---A       master
     \
      C---D newbranch

…---B       staging
```

After merge `newbranch` into `staging` (the merge commit is `E`):

```
…---A          master
     \
      C---D    newbranch
           \
…---B-------E  staging
```

After merge `newbranch` into `master` (the merge commit is `F`):

```
…---A-------F master
     \     /
      C---D newbranch
           \
…---B-------E  staging
```

When you compare `master` with `staging` (master->staging Compare), it will show the commits exist in staging but not exist in master branch (`git log master..staging`). It will show commits `A` and `F` as in the above graph.

When you compare `staging` with `master` (staging->master Compare), it will show the commits exist in `master` but not exist in `staging` branch (`git log staging..master`). It will show commits `B` and `E` as in the above graph.

---

If you want to sync `master` with `staging`, you should merge `staging` into `master`:

```
…---A--------------------F' master
     \                  /
      C---D newbranch  /
           \          /
…---B-------E---------  staging
```

And if you want `master` and `staging` branch are point to the same commit, you can fast forward `staging` branch by merging `master` into `staging`. Then the structure will look like:

```
…---A--------------------F' master, staging
     \                  /
      C---D newbranch  /
           \          /
…---B-------E---------
```